# AngularJs Sanitize not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

The linky works fine but my custom filter isn't giving a sanitized result.
HTML

```
<div class="shoutBody" ng-bind-html="bakars | emoticons | linky:'_blank' "> </div>
```

FILTER:

```
angular.module('ngEmoticons', [])
.filter('emoticons', function() {
    return function(input) {
        var a=input.split(" ");
        console.log(a);
        for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            console.log(a[i]);
            if(a[i] == ":P"){
                a[i]='<a href="hell">great</a>';
            }
        }

        var c=a.join(" ");
        console.log(c);
       return c;
    };
});
```

IT STILL GIVES THE output as  great  but i want it to become link

PS: sanitize module is correctly loaded and filter is injected in the main controller.

Comment: A local lingo for useless talks :P

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
angular.module('ngEmoticons', [])
  .filter('emoticons', function() {
    return function(input) {
      return '<a href="#">' + input + '</a>';
    };
  });
```

Comment: Well i just exchanged the position of linky and emoticons and now it works.